# Why did the definers of the Java Language Specification decide not to allow a Java Thread to restart?

Tags: java, jls, java-threads

While I was reading a book by Kathy Sierra and Bert Bates, I found a passage that says

> Once a thread has been started, it can never be started again.
>   (page 716)

Why did the definers of the Java Language Specification decide not to allow a Java thread to restart ?

Is there a design/architectural reason ?

Comment: Unless the definers wander by, how can anyone answer this? You're correct, a Java thread is not able to restart. If I were to guess, it's because few (if any) threading implementations define restart. I know POSIX threads don't.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Perhaps someone read something written by the definers and that writing said XX is the reason why ? Although I believe my question is slightly different as I am asking the exact design choice over this thread implementation, I see that this post could be a duplicate.